# Telethon functions send_request_code and sign_in are not sent

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

I have the code for handler in my Telegram bot.

The bot is written in aiogram.

```
async def login_and_save_session(session_name, phone_number, call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        await state.update_data(session_file_path=my_files.get_session_file_path(session_name))
        session_file_path = await get_session_file_path_for_session(state=state)
        client = TelegramClient(session_file_path, config.api_id, config.api_hash)
        await client.connect()
        if await client.is_user_authorized():

        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            try:
                await client.sign_in(phone=str(phone_number))
                await handle_request_code(call, state)
                while await get_add_session_flag(state):
                    await asyncio.sleep(3) 
                code = await get_code_for_session(state)
                await client.sign_in(phone=str(phone_number), code=str(code))
            except SessionPasswordNeededError:
                await handle_request_2fa_password(call, state)
                while await get_add_session_flag(state):
                    await asyncio.sleep(3) 
                password = await get_2fa_password_for_session(state)
                await client.sign_in(password=str(password))
            except Exception as e:
                if client:
                    await client.disconnect()
                if session_file_path and os.path.exists(session_file_path):
                    my_files.delete_file(session_file_path)
```

From the logs we can see that the error occurs when trying to send a code or authorize here.

```
        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            try:
                await client.sign_in(phone=str(phone_number))
                await handle_request_code(call, state)
                while await get_add_session_flag(state):
                    await asyncio.sleep(3) 
                code = await get_code_for_session(state)
                await client.sign_in(phone=str(phone_number), code=str(code))
            except SessionPasswordNeededError:
                await handle_request_2fa_password(call, state)
                while await get_add_session_flag(state):
                    await asyncio.sleep(3) 
                password = await get_2fa_password_for_session(state)
                await client.sign_in(password=str(password))
            except Exception as e:
                if client:
                    await client.disconnect()
                if session_file_path and os.path.exists(session_file_path):
                    my_files.delete_file(session_file_path)
```

I am sure that the data format is correct, but the error **bytes or str expected, not <class 'int'> ** comes out

Simplified the function and it worked.

```
async def send_code(phone_number):
    client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash)
    
    await client.connect()
    
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    else:
        
    await client.disconnect()

asyncio.run(send_code(phone_number))
```

But I can't make authorization inside the bot as I mentioned above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the mistake myself.

All I had to do was to specify the parameters in client more precisely...

That's it.

```
client = TelegramClient(session=session_file_path, api_id=config.api_id, api_hash=config.api_hash)
```